# C# Socket double connect?

Tags: c#, sockets, connection, client, connect

I was wondering, If i create a socket in C# and connect it to a server, if i create a thread in the program to try and do annother connectino with the server, will the server see 2 connections from the same place or only one?

The code would look something like this (the socket double-connecting):

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sender.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
        sender.Connect(remoteEP);
```

and then i would have below this code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doubleconnect));
            thread.Start();
public static void doubleconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            sender.Connect(remoteEP);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

I have this question because, on the first part of the code we connect to the server, but we dont close the connection, so by creating a thread and reconnecting i think the server will see as 2 connection from the same client.

So, would the server see this and 2 connection or just one connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

You are calling `Connect` twice on the same `Socket`. I looked in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ych8bz3x(v=vs.110).aspx), but it says nothing about its behaviour if you do that, so I reckon two things can happen:

1. You get an exception on the second `Connect` (probably a `SocketException`)
2. Nothing. As the socket is already connected, it just falls through the second `Connect` call.

But, why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: So each socket represents a new connection? - meaning i would have to have two sockets to get the server to see 2 connections?

Comment: Yes. A socket is exactly that, just like a real (physical) socket.

Comment: Makes sence! grats